# Azure Data Factory Alter Row | Skip Columns while matching Data Between Source and Sink

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We are using ADF pipelines and Alter row transformation to update our data in the sink. While matching source and target data, we want to ignore a column while evaluating data between target and sink.

As an example, in the below case we would like to ignore the TimeStamp column for the match between source and target. Hence we do not want data to be updated in the sink if there is only a difference in the timestamp. Is there a way to achieve this through Alter Row?

Table A - Source

| TimeStamp | First | Last |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 04:01:2021 18:30 | Leo | Messi |
| 03:08:2021 17:30 | Neymar | Jr |

Table B - Existing target

| TimeStamp | First | Last |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 06:04:2022 18:30 | Leo | Messi |
| 06:04:2022 17:30 | Neymar | Jr |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to ignore a column in Alter Row transformation. If you are performing only updates the best way is to remove the mapping of the **TimeStamp** column in Sink mappings so that that record is not changed/updated when the update condition matches.

If you are using Upsert in sink transformation,

**Option1:**

You can make the Timestamp column in the table as default so that even if you remove the mapping of this column in Sink transformation, the default value gets added every time when a new record is inserted and nothing changes when updating.

**Option2:**

•   You add the second Source (target table) and left join the source and target tables.

Source1:

[image]

Source2:

[image]

Join transformation: **Left outer**

[image]

•   Then using derived column transformation, get the source timestamp value only when the target timestamp value is null. This way even when updating the data in the Target table, the same target timestamp value will re-update in the sink.

[image]

•   Using Select transformation, remove target columns and unwanted timestamp columns

[image]

•   Alter row:

[image]

•   Sink:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!, 2nd approach with the join transformation helps